# Trying to fill cells color in excel using openpyxl but receiving an error saying "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'fill'"

Tags: python, tuples, openpyxl, attributeerror

I am trying to create an excel sheet via openpyxl to generate some automated calculations for my firm to replace their manual one. The functionality has been working (*gives pat on back before asking for help), but right now I am trying to format the document to mimic their current one.

In this **for loop**, I am trying create a color-filled cell for the labels of the datas under each column. However, I keep receiving "**AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'fill'**". I tried to cast it to a variable to see if that would help, but it did not. I am a bit of a beginner so I could be overlooking a simple solution. Any insight would be great!

My code:

```
# some of the libs i have that are relevant

from openpyxl.styles import Color, Fill
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
from openpyxl import Workbook


for col in columns[0:i]:
    sheet.merge_cells(col[0]+'6:'+col[2]+'6')
    sheet[col[0]+'6:'+col[2]+'6'].fill = PatternFill(fill_type="solid", start_color="C0C0C0", end_color="C0C0C0")
    sheet[col[0]+'6'].alignment = Alignment(horizontal ="center")
```

The error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 133
    131 for col in columns[0:i]:
    132     sheet.merge_cells(col[0]+'6:'+col[2]+'6')
--> 133     sheet[col[0]+'6:'+col[2]+'6'].fill = PatternFill(fill_type="solid", start_color="C0C0C0", end_color="C0C0C0")
    134     sheet[col[0]+'6'].alignment = Alignment(horizontal ="center")
    135     sheet[col[0]+'6']

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'fill'
```

What it was supposed to look like (just the gray color, the rest of the text and the black strip can be ignored)
[Excel Year Header - Colored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnGoQ.jpg)

Comment: It looks like this is a range:- `sheet[col[0] + '6:' + col[2] + '6']` like `sheet['A6:B6']` so its a tuple of cells. If you were thinking to fill all cells in that range in the one command, it cannot be done. `fill is an attribute for an individual cell reference`. You would need to extract the individual cell object from the tuple. I.e. The style code `sheet[col[0] + '6'].alignment` seems it points to an individual cell and so `sheet[col[0] + '6'].fill` would also be valid.

Comment: @moken Thank you, I will try to cast them to the individual cells and use a couple of extra lines of code. Appreciate the response and the promptness!

Comment: There are many questions/answers on filling cell colour in Excel using Openpyxl here on SO which would be worth reviewing. Also for colour fills Conditional Formatting might also be a consideration as it can be applied to a range rather than individually per cell.

Comment: @moken  I ended up doing each cell individually. It was already in my for loop so i thought a simple but longer solution would be sufficient. Working now! I appreciate your insight.